# Windows 8 and related tags need a little love

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I argued for [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) on SO months ago and created it. With the rush of questions during and after //build/ I now have Taxonomist. But a number of things were announced at //build/ that were secrets before and there is a rush of tagging going on. Some is good, some is not. I am retagging what I see but would like some opinions. I have seen

- [visual-studio-11](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-11) ok
- [visual-studio-2011](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2011) very definitely NOT ok. It is just a fluke that Visual Studio 10 was released in 2010 - VS9 was in 2008. We don't officially know whether VS11 will be in 2011 or 2012 but I would be very surprised if it was this year.
- [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt) ok
- [c++-cx](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b-cx) ok
- [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) (164 questions; not all are Windows 8) and [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) (not ambiguous but only 9 questions used it) we should pick one
- [windows-8](/questions/tagged/windows-8) ok
- [windows-8-preview](/questions/tagged/windows-8-preview) as opposed to what? pointless imo
- [prerelease](/questions/tagged/prerelease) feels like those "year" tags where people would make [visual-studio](/questions/tagged/visual-studio) [2010](/questions/tagged/2010) - am I right? I've been deleting the tag where I see it.
- [c#-5.0](/questions/tagged/c%23-5.0) - should it be 5.0 or just 5?

There may be more. Can we look a little organized here?

Comment: What is [metro] ambiguous with?

Comment: something to do with Tomcat, JaxWS, web services in Java, that kind of thing. I vaguely recognize the words and the other tags and they're not Windows 8 topics at all.

Comment: I disagree that Windows-8 is ok.  There are going to be many many questions that may pertain **only** to the beta phase.  The feature sets, along with their implementation could be anything by the time of release.

Comment: @surfasb with the rumblings of a beta we may now need to distinguish between "developer preview" questions and "beta" questions. What has the pattern been in the past?

Comment: I'd just leave it at preview. All that matters is release. That way we can separate the questions that pertain to release from the ones before.

Comment: I should reword my first comment. The [Windows-8] and [windows-8-preview] coexistence should not be mutually exclusive, since features like winrt aren't likely to change significantly.  Any UI questions and code samples, however, will probably change significantly.

Comment: [c#-5.0] should most definitely come with the point zero.

Answer (score 7):

In the documentation for Windows Developer Preview, they are called "Metro style" apps, not "Metro apps" or "Metro UI apps".  A tag named `metro-style` would be useful here.

Comment: Just search for the tag [tag:metro] on Stack Overflow.  Before Windows 8, "metro" referred to a Web Service interface for Java named Metro.

Comment: You may find that usage of the phrase `Metro style` is more of a trademark or property/branding consideration, the actual tag may need to be something more specific like `windows-metro-ui`.

Comment: I am sure that "Windows", "SQL Server" and "Visual Studio" are all trademarks. That is precisely why they make good tags.

Answer (score 7):

I was monitoring questions related to Metro-Style-Application/WinRT development the past few weeks and noticed the majority of them are tagged [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) or [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt) with occasional references to just [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) that Kate and myself have been fixing to [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) since [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) was related to a Java framework. After I mentioned that in [The great Stack Overflow tag/question cleanup of 2012](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/128315/the-great-stack-overflow-tag-question-cleanup-of-2012/131395#131395) thread - [metro](/questions/tagged/metro) was renamed to [metro-framework](/questions/tagged/metro-framework), so possibly it will get confused less, but then I thought there was really no such thing as "metro-UI" and I noticed the [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) tag was defined as

> Metro is an internal code name for a typography-based user interface design language created by Microsoft. It is featured prominently in Windows Phone 7 and the upcoming Windows 7 successor Windows 8.

This does not really indicate a Metro Style Application or a WinRT-based app since it could also be a Windows Phone 7 app just as well as another app following the "Metro design language" - such as Zune Software, Windows Media Center, [MarkPad](http://code52.org/DownmarkerWPF/) or Visual Studio 11. I added a note to the tag definition to make it a bit clearer:

> Note - this is not exclusive to Windows 8 and is not synonymous to WinRT - the framework for building so called Windows "Metro Style Applications". Use winrt, winrt-xaml, winjs or directx tags for these.

The MSA term is rather unfortunate since WinRT-based apps that go in the Windows Store do not really have to be based in the "Metro design language" that [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) defines. This might be hard to enforce though, so I see two options to help solve it:

1. Get rid of [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) and have it and [metro-style-app](/questions/tagged/metro-style-app) be synonyms for [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt). Then find the few questions tagged [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) that do talk about "Metro design language" and tag them with something like [metro-design](/questions/tagged/metro-design) or [metro-design-language](/questions/tagged/metro-design-language)
2. Change the definition of [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) to say it is about the WinRT-based Metro Style Apps for Windows 8 + perhaps make it redirect to [metro-style-app](/questions/tagged/metro-style-app).
3. Do nothing.

I am leaning towards option 1 and I can go through the 500 [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) questions and review them.

Comment: Option #1 should probably have the retag come before the merge/synonymization. I'm torn between both options, though.

Comment: I'm not sure I have all the privileges to do these myself.

Comment: I know, which is why I mentioned retagging first before attempting a merge.