# Difference between the 'WinRT' and 'metro-ui' tags?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags

I read and write a lot on Stack Overflow about WinRT and Metro UI. I noticed that each of these technologies have their own tag: [winrt](/questions/tagged/winrt) and [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui).

It seems that these tags are used nearly synonymously. I asked myself if it would be a good idea to remap these tags. Currently most questions that are tagged with [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) concern specific problems of WinRT under Windows 8.

I ask me, for what should the [metro-ui](/questions/tagged/metro-ui) tag be for?

- All what is designed in metro style like Win8/RT, WinPhone and tons
  of websites? - I think there are already more specific tags for this.
- Or should this tag be a tag like [wpf](/questions/tagged/wpf) and [silverlight](/questions/tagged/silverlight)?

Another point is that every WinRT App currently comes with Metro UI. Of course, WinRT is more like the back-end or logic, and the Metro UI is only the front end.

Comment: see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/106716/windows-8-and-related-tags-need-a-little-love

Comment: "every WinRT App currently comes with metro ui" Not really.

Comment: It seems to me that WinRT and Metro UI are synonyms like .NET and WinForms are synonyms. Which is to say, they're not.

Comment: @BoltClock's a Unicorn: not? The only exclusion I've curently mind is a background App (these ones are rare). Can you give an example on what apps you think?

Comment: Even if that *was* the only exclusion, Jan, that would still be enough to warrant the distinction. ASP.NET and WebForms were *nearly* synonymous for years, but technically distinct - and now considerably less connected.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

WinRT is essentially the nextgen of win32.  It consists of a number of libraries that stand between your application and the operating system.

Metro is the new UI classes/styles used in WP7 apps and, in future, Win8 apps.

As Metro exists now on WP7, but WinRT does not, you can see that "Metro" does not have a dependency on WinRT.  Metro UI != WinRT.  Whether this changes in future, we'll see.

WinRT can be targeted by C++/CLI, C# and other .NET languages, and *javascript*.  That means you can write a HTML5 application that uses javascript to call into the WinRT libraries.  Therefore WinRT does not imply a Metro UI.